# Getting values from delete function - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a autocomplete box in my aspx page, and from the list if I select any data, am binding the values into a div like this,

```
 var data = "<div class='close'><table><tr><td rowspan='4' width='50px;'>
      <img src='" + studentItem.Photo + "' Width='48' Height='48'  /></td><td>" 
      + studentItem.Name + " ( <span class='stuId'>" + studentItem.StudentId 
      + "</span> )</td><td align='right' ><div class='close16'/></td></tr>
      <tr><td><table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td>" 
      + studentItem.Email + "</td><td>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</td><td>" 
      + studentItem.Mobile + "</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr>
      </table></div>";
```

and am binding the datas into a div like

```
$("#students").append(data);
```

and I can delete particula data like

```
        $(document).on('click', '.close16', function () {
            $(this).parentsUntil('#students').remove();
        });
```

here what I want to do is if I click delete(close16), I need to get the corresponding studentId(which is in the `stuId` ie. span)

I tried like `alert($("stuId").text());` within the click event of `close16`, but its not showing anything, can anyone help me here, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.close16', function () {
    alert($(this).closest('table').find('.stuId').text()); /* span text */
    ...
    $(this).parentsUntil('#students').remove();
});
```